# Remove excess space in ggplot when x axis has dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

My problem is that with ggplot, when the x-axis contains dates a little too muuch excess space is given in the plot on the left side
Is there any possibility for the red space to be removed? so that the whole curve and x-axis is shifted to the left.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(138)
mydat <- (as.Date("2021-04-01")+0:99) %>% as.data.frame()
y <- rnorm(100) 
mydat$val <- y
names(mydat) <- c("Time", "Value")

ggplot(mydat, aes(x=as.Date(Time)))+geom_line(aes(y=Value))+
  scale_x_date(breaks = c(seq(as.Date('2021-04-01'), as.Date('2021-08-01'), by="2 week")) , date_labels = "%d-%b-%y ", limits=c(as.Date('2021-04-01'), as.Date('2021-07-09')))+theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45,size=10, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: You can do so by setting the `limits` and `expand` arguments of `scale_x_date` (or scale in general).

Comment: Adding to the comment by I_O ... that's nothing specific to dates. By default `ggplot2` adds some expansion to both sides of the scale which in case of a continuous scale amounts to 5 percent of the data range (and .6 units in case of discrete scales).  To remove the expansion on the left you could do `scale_x_date(..., expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `expand =c(0,0)` parameter in the `scale_x_date`

[image]